# Praying near a dead body

Tags: tefilla, death

Is there any prohibition against praying under the same roof as a dead body? If I work in a funeral home, and the time for prayer arrives, may I pray in a separate room or should I leave the building entirely?

Comment: Welcome @Nathan. Your question may be improved if you added information as to why you thought it may be a prohibited.

Comment: @bondonk It is forbidden to do mitzvot adjacent to a dead body because it can be seen as making fun of him that he can't do mitzvot anymore. A classic example of this is many men have the practice of tucking in their tzitzit when visiting a cemetery so the mitzva isn't seen. The concept is called Loeg Larash

Comment: @DoubleAA good point. Mishneh Torah Laws of Shema 3:2, SH YD 367:3 etc hold that state one shouldn't daven within a cemetery. This might extend to a funeral home, so it is best to get a psak from your LOR. Either way definitely tuck in your tzitzit and don't daven within 4 amot of a meit. Another room might be ok, depending on what your Rabbi says. Also, don't joke around or act light heartedly around meitim.